# when i run detox test，i get an error info

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, detox

i'm running the demo in [detox/example](https://github.com/wix/Detox/tree/master/examples/demo-react-native-jest). but it can't run the demo normally.

i just run the following command:
1、npm install
2、npm run build:ios
3、npm run test:ios

i just got these error info in my console.

```
detox[30235] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:53335...
detox[30235] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] com.xxx.xxx.xxx.debug launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn BE0CDB30-F235-41D2-BE85-488704F4A504 log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'processImagePath beginsWith "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE0CDB30-F235-41D2-BE85-488704F4A504/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/460C7A3D-F8A1-4876-AFA9-3F227EEFDF64/xxx.app"'
  1) "before all" hook in "{root}"

  0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

why did i get this error info? and what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: If you cloned the Detox project, you need to install lerna and run `lerna bootstrap` in the root Detox folder. If should then work.